# Die not working from perl cgi

Tags: perl, perl-module, mod-perl, mod-perl2

I have perl script which gets spawned from a cgi page and becomes a daemon process running on its own. If there is a die called from any module it is using, the script is getting called although it has been handled in eval block. Though, when I am running the script from the command prompt, everything is fine and the error is getting handled.

Note: From the command line also the script is becoming a daemon

Comment: correction : If there is a die called from any module it is using, the script is getting killed although it has been handled in eval block.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, no real answer here, but some things to look into...

If you're spawning a job from mod_perl remember its more complicated than usual. You need to close the file descriptors, httpd/mod_perl will have more than just 0, 1, and 2 open. We ended up writing a loops which just closed 0 through 255. Also I think `stdout` is not 1 from memory.

But not sure why eval would not be working. Are you spawning you script using `exec`? In which case it should be the same as running it from the shell. When you say its "getting killed" do you mean the die is causing the scirpt to exit (as if there was no eval)? Or something else. If its something else could you possibly be inheriting signal handlers from the httpd process which mod_perl is running in?

Comment: stdin, stdout, and stderr are file descriptors 0, 1, and 2, respectively

Comment: For calling the script from the cgi I have used system call..

system("script_to_daemonize");

In the script I have daemonized it like:

    my $pid;
    if ($pid = fork()) {
        exit 0;

    }
    fatal("Couldn't fork!: $!") unless defined $pid;
    ## trying to set independent session
    setsid() != -1 or fatal("Couldn't setsid(): $!\n");
    $pid = fork and exit;
    fatal("Couldn't fork!: $!") unless defined $pid;

Comment: That looks fine, sorry no idea what your issue is then.